# Facebook Like Button Refusing To Show on Site

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

I have a simple question about the Facebook "like" button. So I'm building a replica site of hulu.com , and so far it's been a breeze and I never thought that this would be such a hassle. I used the web developer tool provided by Facebook to generate the code, so it should be a simple copy and paste from there. But, no matter how much i edit the source, or rearrange the code, NOTHING WORKS. Please take a look and see what you can come up with as being the culprit to my problems.

P.S. : I've tried it on an entirely new HTML document as well, and still nothing is displayed onto the screen.

```
   <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '436365349856529',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

    <div class = "pull-right">
        <p> See what we're watching </p>
       </div>
      <div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try on a real server and remove "https":

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

The code looks fine, so i assume you are trying to test it on your PC without any server. Always use a server, you can also start one on your PC (localhost) - or just upload it to a real one.

Comment: Good to go. Makes sense why it didn't work. Completly overlooked that ! Thanks again

Comment: I usually develop in XAMMP, but I'm being lazy. Laziness costed me valuable time